# UITextview's contentInset & scrollIndicatorInsets with keyboard & rotation in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitextview

i'm using a UITextView and set it's contentInset & scrollIndicatorInsets when keyboard is show/hide like this:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return !self.keyboardShowing
    }

    func keyboardShow(n:NSNotification) {
        self.keyboardShowing = true

        let d = n.userInfo!
        var r = (d[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
        r = self.tv.convertRect(r, fromView:nil)
        self.tv.contentInset.bottom = r.size.height
        self.tv.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = r.size.height
    }

    func keyboardHide(n:NSNotification) {
        self.keyboardShowing = false
        self.tv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        self.tv.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }
```

It works fine, but when I rotated my device, the scrollIndicatorInsets & contentInset didn't change with my new height. So what can I do? Thanks!

NOTE: The view has a Navigation bar on the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` notification. It's sent when the keyboard’s frame has just changed. Actually, you should use the `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` instead of using `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`.